# How to remove jwt token from local storage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, mern

I am new to react and I task is to remove the Jwt token from local storage when the user log out. I have tried on many methods but I failed to do so. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance :)

The code below is my code

my navbar code:

```
const Sidebar = ({auth: {isAuthenticated}},logoutUser) => {

const authlinks=(
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to="/profiles">Developers</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/posts">Posts</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/dashboard">
        <i className="fas fa-user" />{' '}
        <span className="hide-sm">Dashboard</span>
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
        <Link to ="/home">
      <a onClick={logoutUser}>
        <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt" />{' '}
        <span className="hide-sm">Logout</span>
      </a>
      </Link>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
);
const guestLinks = (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to="/profiles">Developers</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
);

  return (

      <Navbar bg="dark" expand="lg" variant="dark">
          
              <Fragment>{isAuthenticated ? authlinks : 
                guestLinks}</Fragment>
                  
              

         
      </Navbar>
    );

  };


Sidebar.propTypes={
    logoutUser: propTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: propTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>({
   auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {logoutUser}) 
(withRouter(Sidebar));
```

the code below is my remove token function:
this function is to remove the token from the local storage

```
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
    localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
    setAuthToken(false);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
}
```

Comment: I think your issue just might be that you're passing in arguments to your component incorrectly. It should be: `const Sidebar = ({auth: {isAuthenticated}, logoutUser })`

Comment: thanks bro, it finally works !!

Comment: Great! I added an official answer if you wouldn't mind marking it as correct and upvoting it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importantly, your `Sidebar` component should only take one argument (props) but right now you have it taking two arguments. You can fix this by fixing how you destructure the props:

```js
const Sidebar = ({auth: {isAuthenticated},logoutUser}) => {
  // logoutUser should work now
}
```